# C++ Getting Pointer to Protected Overriden Function

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member

Why can't you get a pointer to an overriden method in a derived class?

Here's an example:

Base Class

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base 
{

    typedef void (Base::*BasePointer)( void );

public:
    Base(){}

protected:

    virtual void FunFunction( void )
    {

    }

    BasePointer pointer;
};  

#endif  /* BASE_H */
```

Derived Class

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "Base.h"

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        pointer = &Base::FunFunction;

    }

protected:
    // Overrides base function
    void FunFunction( void )
    {

    }
};

#endif  /* DERIVED_H */
```

The constructor in the Derived class attempts to set inherited pointer value equal to the address of the overriden method `FunFunction`. But the error that is generated is "error: 'FunFunction' is a protected member of 'Base'". Changing FunFunction's access to public fixes this problem. FunFucntion can't be public however.

1. Why does it have a problem with `FunFunction` being protected?
2. What is a way to get this desired functionality of this isn't possible?

**EDIT**
Could a solution involve casting `this` to the Base class and then taking the address of the function? Something like `&(((Base*)this)::FunFunction);` although that example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to `Base` protected members only through `Derived`.

At least in VS2012 calling `&Derived::Base::FunFunction` from `Derived` yilds no error. So following code will work:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    typedef void (Base::*BasePointer)( void );


    Base()
    {
        pointer2 = &Base::FunFunction;
    }

protected:

    virtual void FunFunction( void )
    {
        std::cout << "Base::FunFunction\n";
    }

    BasePointer pointer;
    BasePointer pointer2;
};  

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        pointer = &Derived::Base::FunFunction;
    }

    void RunBaseHiddenMethod()
    {       
        (this->*(pointer))();
    }

    void RunFunFunction()
    {
        FunFunction();
    }
protected:
    // Overrides base function
    virtual void FunFunction( void ) override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::FunFunction\n";
    }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Derived d;
    d.RunBaseHiddenMethod();
    d.RunFunFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Derived::FunFunction
Derived::FunFunction
```

Edit: But (as you can see) it will not help you!
In debugger:

> (*((Base*)(&(d)))).pointer    0x00be14ab {ConsoleApplication1.exe![thunk]:Base::`vcall'{0,{flat}}' }'}
>
> (*((Base*)(&(d)))).pointer2   0x00be14ab {ConsoleApplication1.exe![thunk]:Base::`vcall'{0,{flat}}' }'}

The pointer holds just `index` of `virtual` function - not absolute address. Therefore `pointer==pointer2`.

BTW you `can` access `static` `protected` member functions:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    typedef void (BasePointer)(void );
    Base(){}

protected:
    static void FunFunction( void )
    {
        std::cout << "Base::FunFunction\n";
    }

    BasePointer* pointer;
};  

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        pointer = &Base::FunFunction; //OK
    }

    void RunBaseMethod()
    {       
        pointer();
    }
};
```

Another question: why can't we get member function absolute address (like `exported` address)? It is obvious that compiler knows these addresses.

Comment: The first code example doesn't work. It gives the error `error: 'FunFunction' is a protected member of 'Base'`

Comment: It is probably compiler specific. Anyway it was useless.

Comment: I don't think it is compiler specific. This seems like a big design choice in the language.

Comment: I mean this code compiles without error at VC2012. Otherwise I couldn't write `Result:`.

Answer (score -1):

Pure C++ does not allow creating a pointer to a member function of a class unless it is a static function.
Unless you are using C++ Builder, which uses Delphi's trick to create and manage function pointers, what you are trying to do is not possible. Remember a member function of a class has a hidden parameter that points to the instance of the class.

Sam

Comment: This is dead wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker What is so wring about it?

Comment: Read about "pointer to member function".

Comment: **Pure C++ does not allow creating a pointer to a member function of a class unless it is a static**  You can make non-static pointers to member functions?